# Script fails to move the rest of the file due to a file being used by another process

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to make a script
where it takes a zipfile inside a directory,
checks if the zipfile contains a specific name,
and if so, it will move the zipfile to another directory.

Running the following does move the first file.
However, after it moves the first file, it fails to
go through the rest of the file and gives me this error.

"WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
is being used by another process: (here shows the location of the file)"

I wonder what would be the cause of this error.

```
items = os.listdir(location)
Asset_list = os.listdir(drive_location)

def get_list():
    for each in items:
        new_location = drive_location + "\\" + each
        if ".zip" in each:
            selected_zip = location + "\\" + each
            with ZipFile(str(selected_zip)) as zip:
                list_of_files = zip.namelist()
                for each in list_of_files:
                    if Asset_list[5] in each:
                        shutil.move(selected_zip, new_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot continue to check files in the zip file and move it to another location simultaneously. Change `shutil.move` to `shutil.copy` or exit the `with` code block before attempting to move the file. You can just simply add a flag and then copy based on the value of that flag:

```py
items = os.listdir(location)
Asset_list = os.listdir(drive_location)

def get_list():
    
    for each in items:
        new_location = drive_location + "\\" + each
        if ".zip" in each:
            to_move: bool = False
            selected_zip = location + "\\" + each
            with ZipFile(str(selected_zip)) as zip:
                list_of_files = zip.namelist()
                for each in list_of_files:
                    if Asset_list[5] in each:
                        to_move = True
            if to_move:
                shutil.move(selected_zip, new_location)
```

Although I'm not entirely convinced about what exactly the line `if Asset_list[5] in each:` is meant to do. Are you comparing whether one string is contained in the other? Or do you want to compare equality of values? If it's the latter then you need to change it to `if Asset_list[5] == each:`

Comment: Thank you for your help! "if Asset_list[5] in each:" this line compares "each" with a string that is contained inside the "Asset_list" and sees if "each" contains a specific string.